# How to display a Star bullet point on iTunes Connect app description

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

How does one display a 'star shaped' bullet point on the iTunes Connect app description page

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use any Unicode symbol in your app description. Copy and paste will do.

You can find a list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_symbols).

Comment: can we give space between the description using unicode `U+000A` or i just put space and it works? i also want to make some font bold and this unicode is for `U+2022`. right now my looks like something this
`U+000A
U+000A
App Name in bold (can be done)?
U+000A
U+000A
U+2022 list1 
U+2022 list2
`